# JupyterLab Windows desktop version cannot run error: jupyterlab_app Environment not found at: C:\JupyterLab\resources\jlab_s

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

JupyterLab desktop Windows version cannot run.
When I open the software and it raises an error: jupyterlab_app Environment not found at: `C:\JupyterLab\resources\jlab_server\python.exe`

[image]

The main interface of the software displays "Jupyter Server Not Found"

[image]

How to deal with this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Cause of error

The default path during installation was `C:` drive, and I changed the default path to `D:` drive during installation, which caused the dependent resource package to be installed on `D:` drive.

When running the desktop program, `C:\JupyterLab\resources\jlab_server\python.exe` cannot be found

### Solution

1. Copy the `D:\JupyterLab\resources\jlab_server` folder under the `D:` drive path to the `C:\JupyterLab\resources` path, and then reopen the program
2. Re-install the program with the default path.